# How can I use Sails.js actionUtil.js in my controller?

Tags: sails.js

I generated an api `building` using [sails command line](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/command-line-interface/sails-generate#?sails-generate-api-foo) and now I would like to customize logic inside route `/building`. I checked [sails source code](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/blueprints/actions/find.js) to replicate the basic behaviour of `find` action with my customizations.

I saw that the very convenient library [actionUtil](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/blueprints/actionUtil.js) is used to perform this action and I would like to reuse this file in my controller. How can I do that ?

My final goal is just to display buildings which user has access to, if you have a better idea than replicate sails source code, I'm in !

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import it in your controller or wherever you need it with just specifying full path for e.g

> var actionUtil = require('sails/lib/hooks/blueprints/actionUtil');

Answer (score 2):

Santosh Gali's answer is right, but just wanted to suggest a way of achieving what you're after.

I don't know if this is the right way of doing this, but...

If you look at the `parseCriteria` method in actionUtil, you'll find this line: `where = _.merge({}, req.options.where || {}, where) || undefined;`, so you can actually modify the criteria by modifying req.options.where.

So if you create a policy like this one, you should be good to go

`module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.options.where) req.options.where = {};
  req.options.where.owner = req.session.user;
  next();
};`

Of course you'll have to be using sessions and save the user id in it for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can import it just like any other module, by specifying the relative file path from the controller file path.

Comment: So much obvious, thanks ! My bad was that I had sails installed in global mode. By the way, no better idea than replicating sails' source code for what I am attempting to do ?